# Regex pattern for numeric values

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression pattern to only accept positive whole numbers.  It can also accept a single zero.

I do not want to accept decimals, negative numbers, or numbers with leading zeros.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Go to https://regexr.com and try it out!

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

Comment: Should it include an optional comma, in case the format allows it (like 1,000,000)?

Comment: No, It should not accept commas.

Comment: This would do the job: ^(0|[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3,3})*)$

Comment: Can you please explain this Regex?Why @"^\\d$" won't work?

Comment: "^\d$" only does single digits, but "^\d{1,}$" does one or more (Powershell V4 syntax)

Answer (score 21):

"`[1-9][0-9]*|0`"

I'd just use "`[0-9]+`" to represent positive whole numbers.

Comment: if i use grepl("[0-9]+","1111a") in R, it gives me TRUE

Comment: @AmanMathur ^[0-9]+$ then.

Answer (score 19):

This will allow decimal numbers (or whole numbers) that **don't** start with zero:

```
^(([1-9]*)|(([1-9]*)\.([0-9]*)))$
```

If you want to allow numbers that start with zero, you can do :

```
^(([0-9]*)|(([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)))$
```

Comment: These will allow the empty string and '.' by itself.

Answer (score 5):

```
/([1-9][0-9]*)|0/
```

Answer (score 4):

```
/^0|[1-9]\d*$/
```