# regular expression match numeric value

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a pattern:

```
show_clipping.php?CLIP_id=*
```

from:

```
a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="MM_openBrWindow('show_clipping.php?CLIP_id=575','news','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=500,height=400,left=100,top=60')">some text</a>
```

where

```
*
```

can be only numeric values(eg: 0, 1 , 1234)

the result has to return the whole thing(`show_clipping.php?CLIP_id=575`)

what I've tried:

```
show_clipping.php\?CLIP_id=([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])
```

but my attempt would truncate the rest of the digits from 575, leaving the results like:

```
show_clipping.php?CLIP_id=5
```

1. How do I match numeric part properly?
2. Another issue is that the value 575 can contain any numeric value, my regex will not work after 3 digits, how do i make it work with infinit amount of digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what language your are using so here is just the `regex`:

```
'([^']+)'
```

Explanation

```
'       # Match a single quote
([^`])+ # Capture anything not a single quote
'       # Match the closing single quote
```

So basically it capture everything in single quotes, `show_clipping.php?CLIP_id=5` is in the first capture group.

See it action [here.](http://rubular.com/r/16tMnNudYt)

To only capture `show_clipping.php?CLIP_id=5` I would do `'(.*CLIP_id=[0-9]+)'`

```
'        # Match a single quote 
(.*      # Start capture group, match anyting
CLIP_id= # Match the literal string
[0-9]+)  # Match one of more digit and close capture group
'        # Match the closing single quote
```

Comment: can i limit the result to the first group only?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
answered before:
[Regex pattern for numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290513/regex-pattern-for-numeric-values)

(answer number 6)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
onclick.match(/show_clipping\.php\?CLIP_id=\d+/)
["show_clipping.php?CLIP_id=575"]
```

(From the tags of your question I assume you're using JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

```
show_clipping.php\?CLIP_id=(\d+)
```

`\d` matches a digit, and `+` means 1 or more of them.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/(show_clipping.php\?CLIP_id=[1-9]\d*)/
```