# Regex to only allow numbers under 10 digits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to verify that an input is a pure, positive whole number (up to 10 digits, but I'm applying that logic elsewhere).

Right now, this is the regex that I'm working with (which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290513/regex-pattern-for-numeric-values)):

```
 ^(([1-9]*)|(([1-9]*).([0-9]*)))$
```

In this function:

```
if (/^(([1-9]*)|(([1-9]*).([0-9]*)))$/.test($('#targetMe').val())) {
            alert('we cool')
        } else {
            alert('we not')
        }
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work, and I'm not sure if it's the regex or the function. I need to disallow %, . and ' as well. I only want numeric characters. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
/^[0-9]{1,10}$/
```

### Code:

```
var tempVal = $('#targetMe').val();
if (/^[0-9]{1,10}$/.test(+tempVal)) // OR if (/^[0-9]{1,10}$/.test(+tempVal) && tempVal.length<=10) 
  alert('we cool');
else
  alert('we not');
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/sVsfk/)**

Comment: @Siva Charan: this is allowing . and - which i do not want. Can you suggest what i can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

```
var value = $('#targetMe').val(),
    re    = /^[1-9][0-9]{0,8}$/;

if (re.test(value)) {
    // ok
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Would you need a regular expression?

```
var value = +$('#targetMe').val();
if (value && value<9999999999) { /*etc.*/ }
```

Comment: Bad things happen when you interpret `"0000000001"` as a string.

Comment: Bad things happen all the time. Could you elaborate?

Comment: "00000000000000000000001" is more than 10 digits

Comment: If I enter 10 zeros and then a 1, that has length 11 but is only `1` when interpreted as a number.

Comment: Ah, ok. It's all about what the OP needs: I assumed the OP wanted to check *that an input is a pure, positive whole number up to 10 digits ...* '00000000000000000000001' would satisfy that.

Comment: what if we use length property as well i.e **value.length<11** ??

Comment: @Sohail: see A. Wolff's comment

Answer (score 3):

```
  var reg      = /^[0-9]{1,10}$/;
  var checking = reg.test($('#number').val()); 

  if(checking){
    return number;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem with blindly copying code. The regex you copied is for numbers including floating point numbers with an arbitrary number of digits - and it is buggy, because it wouldn't allow the digit `0` before the decimal point.

You want the following regex:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,9}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to match ten digits only:

```
@"^\d{10}$"
```

To find a sequence of ten consecutive digits anywhere in a string, use:

```
@"\d{10}"
```

Note that this will also find the first 10 digits of an 11 digit number. To search anywhere in the string for exactly 10 consecutive digits.

```
@"(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)"
```

Answer (score -1):

check this site here you can learn JS Regular Expiration. How to create this?

https://www.regextester.com/99401

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: I shared a link for test all types of Regular Exp. with detail. here you can understand meaning of Regular Expiration.