# How to validate a html tag which has contenteditable=true?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

For example, in input  tag we have a field called type, where if we put type ="numeric" it doesn't allow to enter anything else than a number.

If I make a td contenteditable  how could I prevent the user from entering anything else than a number in that td tag.

Comment: use html5 pattern attribute pattern="\d*" https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Pattern is only used for input element, right? Atleast that's what it says in the link

Comment: [Here is the link, add this in code to validate your td as numeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197269/regex-to-only-allow-numbers-under-10-digits)

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `.keydown()` method in jQuery . cleaner and concise . see snippet below

```js
$("td").on( "keydown",function(event) {
       if( isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){
           event.preventDefault(); 
       }
})
```

```css
td {
 padding:3px;
 border:1px solid red;
 font-size:18px;
 line-height:24px;
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 <td contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

also, if you want to allow `backspace` and `del` keys ( might be useful ) , change the code to

```js
$("td").on( "keydown",function(event) {
       if(event.which != 8 && event.which !=46 && isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){
           event.preventDefault(); 
       }
})
```

```css
td {
 padding:3px;
 border:1px solid red;
 font-size:18px;
 line-height:24px;
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 <td contenteditable="true"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer but I would like to know if such a work around exists is angular?

Comment: for angular you might want to check the answer Tom gave you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have included the angular tag here.

An [angular directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) for this could be this:

> **src/onlyNumeric.directive.ts**
>
> ```
> import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Directive({ selector: '[onlyNumeric]' })
> export class OnlyNumericDirective {
>
>     @HostListener('input') onContentChange() {
>       this.el.nativeElement.innerText = this.el.nativeElement.innerText.replace(/\D/g,'')
>     }
>
>     constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
>     }
> }
> ```

[**Plunker example here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4l6NWUWcn9lNIKtz7j6K?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#text').keypress(function(e) {
  if (!(e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```js
$('#text').keypress(function(e) {
  if (!(e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name
      <td>
        <p contenteditable="true" id="text">000</p>
      </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: i would replace onkeypress with html5 pattern attribute

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort but could you provide a solution where the input tag is not used, because input tag makes it look. Like a text box and I don't want that

Comment: @geethu jose  This seems to work fine with jquery howsoever what would be an analogy of this exact functionality in angular?