# Extract ids (values) with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have a text

```
[wow id="44"] bla bla bla [wow id="99"] bla bla bla [wow id="100"] bla
```

How do I get the values `44, 99, and  100` in a smart way? Is regex "the way to go" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `preg_match_all()`

```
$str = '[wow id="44"] bla bla bla [wow id="99"] bla bla bla [wow id="100"] bla';
preg_match_all('/[1-9][0-9]*/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);//Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 44 [1] => 99 [2] => 100 ) )
```

For more :- [Regex pattern for numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290513/regex-pattern-for-numeric-values)

Comment: i think this is wrong answer for this case: `id="44" 55 5 65 f5 5 [wow id="44"] bla bla bla`

Answer (score 3):

Use `\K` to discard the previously matched characters from printing in the final output.

```
\[wow id="\K[^"]*(?="])
```

Code:

```
preg_match_all('~\[wow id="\K[^"]*(?="])~', $str, $match);
```

**OR**

Use capturing groups.

```
\[wow id="([^"]*)"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
preg_match_all("/\b(\d{6,20})\b/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

[Here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Bu) is the result.

Answer (score 1):

**php:**

```
 $re = "/\\[[\\w\\s]*id=\"(\\d+)/m";
    $str = " down vote favorite\n    \n\nI have a text\nid=\"44\"\n[wow id=\"44\"] bla bla bla [wow id=\"99\"] bla bla bla [wow id=\"100\"] bla";

    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[See live](http://regex101.com/r/qW3lF4/1)